# Some Sources in one element in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an application with mvvm. 
In my ViewModel i have 2 ObservableCollection.
One of them binding good like this:

```
        <phone:LongListSelector
                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceMatrix}"
                x:Name="LongListSelector_Matrix" 
                Loaded="Event_LongListSelector_OnLoaded_Matrix"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Matrix}"
                GridCellSize="20, 20"
                LayoutMode="Grid"
                FontSize="10"
                Padding="10,0,-5,0" Tap="asd" 
                                     />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

But now i need binding to this LongListSelector from another ObservableCollection like this:

```
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="SE Матрица">
            <phone:LongListSelector
                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceMatrix}"
                x:Name="LongListSelector_Matrix" 
                Loaded="Event_LongListSelector_OnLoaded_Matrix"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Matrix}"
                GridCellSize="20, 20"
                LayoutMode="Grid"
                FontSize="10"
                Padding="10,0,-5,0" Tap="asd" 

                Background="{Binding  Source= ItemSourceMatrixBackground, Path=Colors_Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                                     />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

But the code (Background="....) above dont work. There are my template:

```
    <!--   Matrix   -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Matrix">
        <TextBlock  x:Uid="{Binding Matrix_Name}" 
                    Text="{Binding Matrix_Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    FontSize="{Binding Matrix_FontSize}"
                    Foreground="{Binding Matrix_Foreground}"                     
                   />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: hat does your viewmodel look like? where is `ItemSourceMatrixBackground.Colors_Value` defined?

Comment: ItemSourceMatrixBackground - it's an ObservableCollection in ViewModel Class.